# strongAuthenticationEmail and strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber attributes in Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I would like to store both, an email address and a phone number for MFA in Azure AD B2C and found the properties above. However, when writing one of the attributes, the other one seems to be getting purged. Unfortunately, I found very little information about MFA attributes in AAD. Any Idea on how to handle this?

Answer (score 2):

These two attributes are protected attribute and inaccessible with Graph API, hence lack of public docs. With AAD B2C, you will write to these attributes within a User Flow when the user signs up with a Username (strongAuthenticationEmail), or enrols for MFA (strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber). But these cannot be read/write by Graph API by you.

If you use Custom Policies, you have full control over where you store the data, in the case where you need to feed in these attributes/prepopulate, or require an Admin pane to manage these attributes outside of the B2C Policy execution, simply use an extension attribute instead and configure the Custom Policy to R/W from the extension attribute, rather than the mentioned protected attributes.

Comment: Thanks, @JasSuri - That's what I was doing. However, I found out that when writing strongAuthenticationEmail and strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber at the same time and with the same technical profile, both are persisted. When having separate profiles to persist only one of the attributes, the other one is gone afterwards. I solved this by getting all current values and re-writing both, also if only one is getting updated. From what I observed, this behaves like both being part of the same collection (similar to AlternativeSecurityId).

Comment: That's weird and unexpected.